# Download zip file laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Gettin this error when im trying to download zip file

```
The file "C:\wamp\www\Petro\public\download/downloads.zip" does not exist
```

My code

```
if (\File::exists('download/downloads.zip')) {
     $directory = public_path('download');
     $success   = \File::cleanDirectory($directory);

       foreach($checked as $check){
        $path = File::where('name',$check)->select('real_path')->first();
        $img = \Image::make($path->real_path);
        $img->save(public_path('download'). '/'. $check);
       }

   } else {
       foreach($checked as $check){
        $path = File::where('name',$check)->select('real_path')->first();
        $img = \Image::make($path->real_path);
        $img->save(public_path('download'). '/'. $check);
     }
  }

       $files = \File::files('download');
       \Zipper::make('download/downloads.zip')->add($files);
       $pathtoFile = public_path('download/downloads.zip');
       return response()->download($pathtoFile);
```

The zip is created but i cant download it, what is wrong with my code?

When i use `dd($files)` after create the zip :

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "download/batman.jpg"
  1 => "download/batmanfamily.jpg"
  2 => "download/batwoman.jpg"
  3 => "download/daredevil.jpg"
]
```

There is not zip file but if i check in my local directory the zip is created.
Can you guys give me a hand with this and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error you have `/` instead of `\` this.

```
The file "C:\wamp\www\Petro\public\download/downloads.zip" does not exist
                                           ^
                                          Here
```

change `/` in following line to `\`:

```
 $pathtoFile = public_path('download/downloads.zip');
```

To

```
 $pathtoFile = public_path('download\downloads.zip');
```

Comment: Same error `The file "C:\wamp\www\Petro\public\download\downloads.zip" does not exist`

Comment: can you check the permissions ? that might create the problem. try changing the files permission to 777 for debugging and check if u can see the file in `dd()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the process.

```
Zipper::make('download/downloads.zip')->add($files)->close();
```